# UnassignedReferenceException but it seems clearly assigned?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

BreakableObject script is a foreign script that came attached to describe how barrels exploded. When those barrels explode, I want a new object to pop up in their place. So I've added the following to the top of the code:

```
public class BreakableObject:MonoBehaviour{
public GameObject gamePiece2;
```

One of the methods in this class, which houses the overall process, is coded as follows. Unimportant lines have been dashed out.

```
public void triggerBreak() {
    //if(transform.parent.CompareTag("Winner"))
    
    //{
        //Destroy(transform.FindChild("object").gameObject);
        //Destroy(transform.GetComponent<Collider>());
        //Destroy(transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        //StartCoroutine(breakObject());
        //foreach (Transform child in transform.parent)
        //{
        //  GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
        //}
        //animalSpawn = Random.Range(0, 4);
        Instantiate(gamePiece2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Lastly, I have verified (with 'Find References in Scene') that this script is only applied to one empty Game Object titled 'Animal Array' and that I have assigned a reference object in the inspector, as seen the attached picture.

Nonetheless, I still get an 'UnassignedReferenceException' saying that gamePiece2 of BreakableObject has not been assigned. Any thoughts?

@UnholySheep: My main script is called game manager. This is a side script defining when a barrel will explode. My goal is to have it instantiate an object where the barrel was right when it explodes. It seems easiest to do that in the barrel script.

This image is where I thought I assigned it

[image]

Comment: Can you show us where `gamePiece2` is assigned. I can only see it's declaration in what you've shown us.

Comment: Would be great to see the code where you assign gamePiece2, from what you have shown us it will never be assigned to.

Comment: How exactly is this method being called? E.g.: please show how you retrieve the gameobject this script is attached to

Comment: All three of you are alluding to me fundamentally misunderstanding the same step. I'm googling it and not finding it. I was of the opinion I was assigning the variable when I dragged the prefab onto the inspector as seen in the image link above

Comment: Either it's null or you're making it null. Check the rest of the script and see if you're setting its value somewhere. Watch it in play mode and see if the value goes null. Set a breakpoint and see if it's null. Add `[SerializeField]` and then make it private and see if you get a compile error (because another script is trying to access it). There are a lot of things that could be going wrong here but you haven't provided the whole script so it's hard to debug for you.

Comment: Okay I solved it. To sum up as best I can/understand:  Despite applying the script to the empty GameObject I had created, I had to also go and assign gamePiece2 to the original barrels the code was written for.